# BM25Similarity in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Does the current version of the Azure Cognitive Search API support BM25Similarity? I could not find that in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The availability of BM25Similarity depends on the age of your search service. If you created the service after July 15, 2020 then BM25Similiarity is the default ranker.

For older services, you can enable BM25 by setting a Similarity property on new indexes. The property is only exposed on new indexes, so if want BM25 on an existing index, you'll have to drop and rebuild the index with a new Similarity property set to "Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity".

Comment: Adding to what @user16432901 mentioned, here's a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-ranking-similarity